# Can I create a generic list of a particular interface in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, generics, interface, delphi-xe3

In C# I can create a generic list that contains a specific Interface, such as:

```
myList = List<IMyInterface>;
```

Can I do the same thing in Delphi XE3, and if so how?

I know I can create a TInterfaceList to store a list of interfaces but it's not strongly typed
so I would still need to cast when using objects in the list.

Is there a strongly typed way of doing this?

Comment: what is wrong with `TList<IMyInterface>` ?

Comment: Thank you!, seems so obvious now. I was previously playing with TObjectList and that wouldn't work because an interface is not an object. I then focused on TInterfaceList and never thought to use a simple TList. Anyway, it works, so thanks again.

Comment: @Serg Why isn't this an answer. Steve needs an answer to accept.

Comment: Ok, I thought Steve could answer the question himself :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Delphi supports generic List class `TList<T>`, that can be used with specific interface, for example:

```
var
  List: TList<IMyInterface>;

begin
  List := TList<IMyInterface>.Create;
  {..Do something with list..}
  List.Free;
end;
```